# How to replace *every* occurrence of a string in an NGINX response header with another value?

Tags: nginx, http-headers, reverse-proxy

I have an Nginx setup that is using `proxy_pass` that talks to an internal server and returns the response. What I'd like to do - can I replace every instance of a specific string in a specific header with another word?

The `proxy_pass` points at an internal server, and in the response sends this header:

```
WWW-Authenticate: Bearer realm="https://someinternal.domain/v2/token",service="https://someinternal.domain/v2/token"
```

I'd like this to be overridden, replace the 'someinternal' strings with 'mypublic'

```
WWW-Authenticate: Bearer realm="https://mypublic.domain/v2/token",service="https://mypublic.domain/v2/token"
```

I'm aware of nginx's `sub_filter`, but that only seems to work on the body of the response, but not the headers.
I'm aware of `proxy_redirect`, but that only applies to the Location header.
So this question boils down to - how can I perform these URL replacements in custom headers?

---

I do have something working, but it feels inelegant; it'd be great if I could just replace all occurrences without knowing the structure of the header.

```
map $upstream_http_www_authenticate $newvalue {
  ~(.*)(someinternal)(.*)(someinternal)(.*)  $1mypublic$3mypublic$5;
  default "";
}

server {
    listen 80;

    location / {
      proxy_pass https://someinternal.domain/;
      proxy_hide_header 'WWW-Authenticate';
      add_header WWW-Authenticate $newvalue always;
    }
}
```

I'm using Nginx's `map` with regex to look for the 'someinternal' and then reconstructing the header with 'mypublic' in between the regex matches. I then use `proxy_hide_header` to hide the internal header, and add its replacement.

Comment: did you find any elegant solution to this?

Comment: I wasn't able to, I'm just living with my inelegant solution now.